# Youtube-DL: How to strip video information/description when converting audiofile to MP3?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, mp3, youtube-dl

This might be picky, but when I use Youtube-DL to convert audio from a video to MP3, I let it also tag the title and embed the thumbnail from the video. Somehow it adds the video description and some other meta video info, which I don't want.
This is the command I use:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s" <youtube url>
```

When I check the ID3 tag info, it added the video title as expected. If I rename the extension to AVI, play the audio file, and open its properties, I can see unwanted info like the video description, version encoder, and brand.
The option `--add-metadata` writes metadata to the video file, from which it gets the video description, but when I leave that out, the video does not get tagged at all.

I read through the documentation of Youtube-DL and FFMPEG, but I can’t find a proper way to strip the video description/info and keep the MP3 tagged.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe you can currently control the `--add-metadata` option.

However you can use the `--exec` option to execute a command afterwards using the reference to the output file `{}` and ask `ffmpeg` to strip the unwanted metadata like so:

`--exec "ffmpeg -y -i {} -map 0 -c copy -metadata comment=\"\" -metadata description=\"\" -metadata purl=\"\" temp.mp3"`

Performing the "convert" process in place (overwriting the same file) breaks the stream data of the output file but adding an auxiliary `temp.mp3` and then overwriting it makes it work like a charm.

I've tested the following command combination:

```
youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s" <youtube url> --exec "ffmpeg -y -i {} -map 0 -c copy -metadata comment=\"\" -metadata description=\"\" -metadata purl=\"\" temp.mp3;cp -r temp.mp3 {};rm -rf temp.mp3"
```

I hope this helps!

PS: I know the question is a bit old but posting a working solution might help you and others.

Comment: I had to add "-id3v2_version 3" to the ffmpeg line to be visible to "id3v2 -l" command